# Issue with Spivak's Solution

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Here was the problem:

[image]

Here is the solution from his solutions book:

[image]

This is barely a proof.  How can he just say let $f(c) = 0$? How do you prove that $f(c) =0$ and how do you prove that $f(d) = 0$?

How can I use the IVT to prove that criterion? Thanks!

Comment: Typo? Note that $c\notin [a,x_0],d\notin [x_0,b]$ according to the picture.

Comment: @Eupraxis1981 I'd assume c and d were switched by mistake

Comment: The text of the argument looks right to me. For instance, in finding $c$: We know there is at least one $x \in [a, x_0]$ such that $f(x) = 0$, namely $x = a$; i.e., the set $A = \{  x \in [a, x_0]  : f(x) = 0\}$ is not empty. What's tricky is to show that $A$ contains its own maximum; I'm guessing that's part of what the hint is referring to.

Comment: Looking up Spivak, this 'tricky part' is exactly what problem 3 requires you prove.

Comment: I must say that this is a very good question (+1) as OP has figured out that there is something creepy here. Most textbooks, while discussing IVT, don't elaborate/emphasize on the following fact. **If $f(x)$ is continuous in $[a, b]$ and $k = f(x)$ for some $x \in [a, b]$ then there is a least value of $x \in [a, b]$ for which $f(x) = k$ and there is a greatest value of $x \in [a, b]$ for which $f(x) = k$**.

Comment: Normally while proving IVT, it is shown that for any $k$ lying between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ there is a $c \in (a, b)$ such that $f(c) = k$. It should also be emphasized that continuity gives an extra guarantee that there is a minimum/maximum value of $x$ for which $f(x) = k$. This is something which should be mentioned while discussing IVT (although this is an extra feature apart from IVT).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apart from the fact that the labels $c$ and $d$ in the graph have been interchanged, there’s nothing wrong with the argument. The set of $x\in[a,x_0]$ such that $f(x)=0$ is non-empty because it contains $a$, and it’s closed because $f$ is continuous, so it has a largest element, which we’ll call $c$. $f(x_0)\ne 0$, so $c<x_0$. The existence of $d$ follows by similar reasoning applied to the interval $[x_0,b]$.

If you don’t know about closed sets at this point, the problem is harder: you have to show that $A=\{x\in[a,x_0]:f(x)=0\}$ actually has a maximum. It certainly has a supremum (least upper bound) $u$, since it’s bounded above by $x_0$. And if $u\notin A$, there must be a sequence $\langle y_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ in $A$ converging to $u$. Continuity of $f$ then implies that $\langle f(y_n):n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $f(u)$ and hence that $f(u)=0$, i.e., that $u\in A$ after all.

Comment: So you are letting $c=a$ and $d = b$ then $f(c) = f(a) = f(d) = f(b) = 0$ what allows you to let $c \to a$?

Comment: @Amad27: No, that is not at all what I’m doing. I’m defining the set $A$ and showing that it has a largest element, which I call $c$. (And similarly for the other side.)

Comment: How does the largest element have property that $f($largest element)$ = 0$? SO if $c$ is the largest how is it true that $f(c) = 0$?

Comment: @Amad27: $A$ is the set of points in $[a,x_0]$ at which $f(x)=0$. Obviously, then, $f(x)=0$ whenever $x\in A$. By definition. By definition $c$ is the largest element of $A$. Forget largest for a moment: $c$ **is in** $A$. Therefore $f(c)=0$. There is absolutely nothing to question about that statement. I could understand it if you wondered how we know that $A$ **has** a largest element, though I did in fact sketch a proof of that in my answer; asking why an element of $A$ has the property that characterizes elements of $A$, on the other hand, makes no sense at all.

Comment: This is a good answer, I just have one question. How do you say that $c \in A$??

Comment: @Amad27: I **defined** $c$ to be the largest element of $A$. There’s nothing to prove there. The only thing that needs to be proved before I can do that is that $A$ **has** a largest element, and that follows from continuity of $f$.

Comment: Okay. I see. But then does letting $c = \sup A$ fulfill the requirement that $f(x) > 0$ for c < x < d ???

Comment: @Amad27: If ensures that $f(x)>0$ for $c<x<x_0$; the choice of $d$ takes care of the other side of the interval. It does this because the choice of $c$ ensures that $f(x)\ne 0$ for $c<x\le x_0$, by the definition of $A$. We know that $f(x_0)>0$, so if we had $f(x)<0$ for some $x$ with $c<x<x_0$, the intermediate value theorem would tell as that $f(y)=0$ for some $y$ with $x<y<x_0$. But then $y$ would be an element of $A$ bigger than $c$, contradicting the choice of $c$. Therefore no such $x$ exists, and $f(x)>0$ on the interval $(c,x_0]$.

Comment: Scott, excellent answer, unbeatable. Let me try for $x_0 \le x < d$. Suppose $f(x) < 0$ then by IVT, a contradiction. But so one more thing. How does the choice of $c$ ensure that $f(x) \ne 0$ for $c < x \le x_0$? Thanks!

Comment: @Amad27: You’re welcome! Recall that $A$ was defined to be the set of $x\in[a,x_0]$ such that $f(x)=0$, and $c=\max A$. If we had $f(x)=0$ for some $x$ with $c<x\le x_0$, that $x$ would be a member of $A$ bigger than $c$, which is impossible: $c$ is the largest element of $A$.

Comment: Sir Brian M. Scott,I hope you do not mind me asking another question please? I relooked at more definitions to understand this better. We said: $u = c = \sup A$. Then continuity will imply that $y_n$ converges to $f(c)$ but that still doesnt show that $f(c) = 0$ though does it?

Comment: @Amad27: We have the $y_n$’s converging to $u$, and $f$ is continuous, so the $f(y_n)$’s have to converge to $f(u)$. But all of the $f(y_n)$’s are $0$, so they converge to $0$, and $f(u)$ must be $0$. But then by definition $u\in A$.

Comment: Brian M Scott, thanks once again for the reply! Also the meaning of supremum. If a set here $A$ has a supremum.The supremum doesnt have to suffice that $f(x) = 0$ right? I mean in general, does the supremum of a set need to suffice the set's condition?

Comment: @BrianMScott, sorry I forgot to ping you! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Amad27: No, it depends on the condition. Consider the function $f(x)=x$, and let $A=\{x\in\Bbb R:f(x)<0\}$; then $\sup A=0$, but $0\notin A$, because $f(0)=0\not<0$.

Answer (score 11):

$$c:=\max\{x\in[a,x_0]|\ f(x)=0\}$$

By definition $c\in\{x\in[a,x_0]|\ f(x)=0\}$. Therefore $f(c)=0$. Similarly for $f(d)=0$.

More interesting is to show that such maximum exists. We can define instead
$$c':=\sup\{x\in[a,x_0]|\ f(x)=0\}$$
which always exists. By definition of supremum there is a sequence $x_n\in\{x\in[a,x_0]|\ f(x)=0\}$ such that $x_n\to c'$. But, because $f$ is continuous, then $f(c')=\lim f(x_n)=\lim 0=0$. Therefore $c'\in\{x\in[a,x_0]|\ f(x)=0\}$, i.e. $c'$ is actually a maximum.

The other interesting part is to show that $f(x)>0$ for $x\in[c,d]$. Assuming $f(x)=0$ for some $x\in[c,d]$ is a contradiction with the definition of $c$ and $d$. Assuming that $f(x)<0$ for some $x\in[c,d]$ gives a point in $[x,x_0]$ where $f$ vanishes. This again contradicts the definition of $c$ and $d$.

Comment: which Definition of Supremum is this? Spivak shows nothing like this?

Comment: @Amad27 All definitions of supremum. Whichever definition you are using it will define supremum $c'$ as the smallest upper bound. In particular, for every $n$, we must have that $c'-1/n$, which is smaller than $c'$, can't be an upper bound (because $c'$ is the smallest one). Therefore there are elements of the set that are in $[c'-1/n,c']$. Let $x_n$ be one such element. Then we have $x_n\to c'$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: can I get a formal definition online?

Comment: @Amad27 [supremum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum#Formal_definition)

Answer (score 4):

Here's the tricky part of the proof that's getting swept under the rug:

> **Lemma:** There *exists* a largest $x \in [a,x_0]$ such that $f(x) = 0$

In order to prove this, it suffices that the set $\{x \in [a,x_0]: f(x) = 0\}$ is a closed subset of a bounded set.  Perhaps this approach is overly sophisticated, though.

If we want to stick to simpler methods, we can proceed as follows: define
$$
c = \sup\{x \in [a,x_0]:f(x) = 0\}
$$
Suppose that $f(c) \neq 0$. Then by continuity, there is a $\delta>0$ such that $f(x) \neq 0$ for $x \in (c-\delta,c)$, which means that $c$ cannot be the supremum as it was defined.

Thus, we conclude $f(c) = 0$, so that $c$ is the largest $x$ in $[a,x_0]$ such that $f(x) = 0$.

Comment: Why not just closed subset of a bounded set? All you want to do is apply $\sup$, so you don't really need compactness.

Comment: What does it mean "there exists a largest $x \in [a, x_0]$ such that $f(x) = 0$ I mean, how do you interpret this? What does this even mean? "largest?"

Comment: @Amad27 we've defined $c$ so that $f(c)=0$ and  if $x\in [a,x_0] and $f(x)=0$, then $x\leq c$. That's what it means.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen point taken. It was just what came to mind first.

Comment: How can you say $c$ is in that set? Also, do it suffice that $f(x) >0$ for c < x < d?

Comment: All of that is written in my proof

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate on my comments, I will establish the following:

**IVT (Stronger form): Let $f$ be continuous on $[a, b]$ with $f(a) \neq f(b)$ and let $k$ be a number between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$. Then there is a least value of $x \in (a, b)$ for which $f(x) = k$ and there is a greatest value of $x \in (a, b)$ for which $f(x) = k$.**

The proof below is taken from Hardy's Pure Mathematics (and this book emphasizes this stronger version of IVT) and is based on Dedekind's Theorem.

Let's assume that $f(a) < f(b)$ so that $f(a) < k < f(b)$. Divide the numbers $x \in [a, b]$ into two sets $L$ and $R$ such that $x \in L$ if the values of $f$ on each point of the interval $[a, x]$ are less than $k$. Put remaining numbers in $R$ so that $R = [a, b] - L$. It should be clear now that since $f(a) < k$ there is small neighborhood of type $[a, a + h]$ where values of $f$ are less than $k$, hence all points of $[a, a + h]$ belong to $L$ and hence $L$ is non-empty. Also clearly $b \in R$ (because $f(b) > k$) so that $R$ is also non-empty (in fact $R$ contains all points of interval $[b - \delta, b]$ for a suitable small $\delta$). It can be seen from the definitions of $L, R$ that they form a Dedekind cut and hence there is a unique number $\alpha \in [a, b]$ such that for all  numbers $x \in [a, \alpha)$ belong to $L$ and all numbers $x \in (\alpha, b]$ belong to $R$. Also it is clear that $a < \alpha < b$ (because $[a, a + h] \subseteq L$ and $[b - \delta, b] \subseteq R$).

We will show that $f(\alpha) = k$. On the contrary assume that $f(\alpha) < k$. Then by continuity there is a small interval of type $[\alpha - \epsilon, \alpha + \epsilon]\subseteq [a, b]$ where all the values of $f$ are less than $k$. But $\alpha - \epsilon < \alpha$ and so $\alpha - \epsilon \in L$ and hence all the values of $f$ in $[a, \alpha - \epsilon] $ are less than $k$. It follows that values of $f$ in interval $[a, a + \epsilon]$ are less than $k$. So $\alpha + \epsilon \in L$ and this is a contradiction because all numbers in $(\alpha, b]$ belong to $R$.

A similar contradiction can be attained if we assume that $f(\alpha) > k$. It follows that $f(\alpha) = k$. Also since all the numbers of $[a, \alpha)$ belong to $L$ it follows that the values of $f$ in $[a, \alpha)$ are less than $k$. Therefore $\alpha$ is the least value of $x \in [a, b]$ for which $f(x) = k$.

By modifying the definitions of $L, R$ we can show that there is a greatest number $\beta \in (a, b)$ for which $f(\beta) = k$. For this we need to define $R$ to contain all points $x$ of $[a, b]$ for which the values of $f$ in $[x, b]$ are greater than $k$ and $L = [a, b] - R$.

This proof of IVT based on Dedekind's theorem has the advantage that it gives a stronger result.

For the current question we can see that $c$ is the least value of $x \in [x_{0}, b]$ for which $f(x) = 0$ and $d$ is the greatest value of $x$ in $[a, x_{0}]$ for which $f(x) = 0$.

Comment: Although it's certainly true that this is a stronger result, I'm not sure why it's “creepy” to omit it from the statement of the IVT.  IMO the version in Spivak is cleaner.  It's a pure translation of the topological fact that the continuous image of a connected set is connected.  And Spivak *did* elaborate on it in the exercises.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang: Sorry if the word "creepy" sounds offensive. My point was to highlight this feature when discussing IVT. IVT statement should not change because historically it deals with the existence of a "c" and not least and greatest "c". Also from my experience with many questions on MSE, I think that students are having real problem in solving in Spivak exercises. Some students might be put off by this and might leave the starred exercise. Hence I prefer that textbooks should avoid deep concepts in exercises and include them in the text portion.

Comment: Would the following not be an easier argument, from the weak to strong IVT? Clearly $\{k\}$ is a closed set, so the set $S=\{\, x\mid f(x)=k\,\}$ is also closed since $f$ is continuous. Then with some $x_0\in S$ given by the weak version of IVT, one has $\inf(S\cap(a,x_0])\in S$ and $\sup(S\cap[x_0,b))\in S$, and these satisfy the requirements of the strong version.

Comment: @Paramanand: I think we have a difference of opinion on what exercises are for. :-) When a student gets stuck, asks questions, then gets unstuck, that is when the student learns.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: fully agree with you. I was just trying to present Hardy's proof.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang: It is the difference of opinion which makes things interesting. World would be totally boring if everyone had same point of view. I therefore respect your point of view. :)

Comment: @ParamanandSingh (+1) I have a question. When we say let $c = \sup A$ does $c$ necessraily have to suffice $f(c) = 0$?

Comment: @Amad27: It is not necessary that $f(c) = 0$, but for continuous $f$ it will always be the case that $f(c) = 0$. This is what makes continuous functions interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem (what actually bothers and confuses you here) is the choice of notation, not the proof by itself.

So, the problem requires to prove existence of $c$ and $d$ that satisfy certain condition.

The hint from the book starts with: *Let $c$ is such and such and $d$ is such and such.* And, the rest of the proof should follow.

However, the better, clearer way would be: *Let $e$ is such and such and $f$ is such and such.* Than you prove that $e$ and $f$ are truly $c$ and $d$ you are looking for.

Comment: You certainly want to avoid having to say something like "we have shown that $f(e)=0=f(f)$ and that...". Apart from that, it is perfectly normal, in proving that there exists some $c$ with a given property, that one should at some point say "let $c$ be..." to give a concrete witness of that existence.