# Conditions for a supremum of a set.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Suppose a function $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ and there exists, $x_0 \in (a, b)$ such that $f(x_0) > 0$. And then define a set,

$$A = \{ a \le x < x_0 \space | \space f(x) = 0   \}$$

We say $c = \sup A$

Does $c$ necessarily have to suffice that $f(c) = 0$ ? ?  Why/ why not?

I am confused about sets so this will be helpful!

Comment: $A$ might be empty. Is there some additional condition on $f$, such as $f(a)=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, provided that $A$ is not empty: Since $c$ is the supremum of $A$, we find a sequence $(x_n)\subset A$ of elements of $A$ converging to $c$. Since each number $x_n$ is an element of $A$, we must have $\color{blue}{f(x_n)=0}$. Since $f$ is $\color{green}{\text{continuous}}$, we conclude
\begin{align*}
f(c)=f\left(\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n\right)\color{green}=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)\color{blue}=\lim_{n\to\infty}0=0.
\end{align*}

Comment: Look here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1110664/issue-with-spivaks-solution/1110684?    They just say let $c = \sup A$ and they say the sup doesnt have to suffice the conditions?

Comment: Where did they say that $c$ doen't have to satisfiy $f(c)=0$? Look at the answers and the comments. All of them say $f(c)=0$, and one of them just used the same proof as I did.

Comment: Okay then how can they simply say: Let $c = \sup A$ without even knowing if $f(c) = 0$?

Comment: If $A$ is bounded from above and not empty, then the supremum exists. And then you can prove, as I tried to do, that $f(c)=0$.