# Limit of a sequence of a supremum.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing

**Problem:** Suppose that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and that $f(a)<f(b)$. Prove that there are numbers $c$ and $d$ with $a\leq c < d \leq b$ such that $f(c)=f(a)$ and $f(d)=f(b)$ and $f(a)<f(x)<f(d)$ for all $x$ in $(c,d)$.

How do we choose a set?

I was thinking:

$$A = \{a \le x | f(x) = f(a)   \}$$

$$B = \{x \le b | f(x) = f(b)   \}$$

And consider: $c = \sup A$ and $d = \inf B$

But I am not sure how to use a sequenence or a limit to get that $f(c) = f(a)$ I know it can be done, but how?  **I am VERY new to that concept.**

Comment: Hint: take $A = \{x \in (a,b) : f(x) > f(a) \}$, $c = \inf A$, and $B = \{x \in (c,b) : f(x) > f(b)\}$.

Comment: The solution you suggested wouldn't work because you might end up with $c > d$.

Comment: See a related question http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1110664/72031

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is the right idea, but you need a few more details.

Let $c = \sup \{ t \in [a,b] | f(t) = f(a) \}$, then we have $c <b$ and $f(c) = f(a)$ by continuity. Furthermore, $f(x) > f(a)$ for all $ x > c$.

Now let $d = \inf \{ t \in [c,b] | f(t) = f(b) \}$. We have 
$c < d$ and $f(d) = f(b)$. Furthermore, $f(x) < f(b)$ for all $ c \le x < d$,
and from above we have $f(a)=f(c) < f(x) < f(d)=f(b)$ for all $x \in (c,d)$.

**Addendum**: To show why $f(c) = f(a)$:
Let $S=\{ t \in [a,b] | f(t) = f(a) \}$ and $c = \sup S \le b$. By definition of $\sup$, for all $\epsilon>0$ we can find some $t \in S$ such that $t > c-\epsilon$. So, let $\epsilon={1\over k}$ and let $t_k \in S$ be such that
$t_k > c-{1 \over k}$. Note that $t_k \le c$, since $c$ is the $\sup$, hence we have
$|c-t_k| < {1 \over k}$. This shows that $t_k \to c$. Since $f$ is continuous, we have $f(c) = \lim_k f(t_k)$, and since $t_k \in S$ we have
$f(t_k) = f(a)$ for all $k$ we have $f(c) = f(a)$.

Comment: but how, $f(c) = f(a)$ by continuity?

Comment: Let $t_k \in S=\{ t \in [a,b] | f(t) = f(a) \}$ such that $t_k \to c$, such a sequence exists by definition of $\sup$. Since $t_k \to c$, continuity gives $f(c) = \lim_k f(t_k)$. Since $t_k \in S$, we have $f(t_k) = f(a)$, hence $f(c) = f(a)$.

Comment: lets work one step at a time. **(1)** $t_k$ is a sequence right? and as $k \to \infty $ you are saying $t_k \to c$? What allows you to say so?

Comment: @Amad27: I added some notes to address your question above.

Comment: copper.hat Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This is another approach which avoids $\sup$ and $\inf$.

As mentioned in [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1110812/72031) there is a last value of $x$ in $[a, b]$ for which $f(x) = f(a)$. This value of $x$ we denote by $c$. Clearly $a \leq c < b$. Also note that if $x > c$ then $f(x) > f(c) = f(a)$ (why?). Similarly there is a first value of $x \in [c, b]$ for which $f(x) = f(b)$. This value of $x$ we call $d$ and $c < d \leq b$. Also we have $f(x) < f(b) = f(d)$ for all $x \in [c, d)$. Thus it follows that we have two points $c, d$ such that $a \leq c < d \leq b$ and $f(a) = f(c) < f(x) < f(d) = f(b)$ for all $x \in (c, d)$.

Comment: @Amad27: You should see the linked answer which has a proof.

Comment: But that only applies for $0$ doesnt it?

Comment: @Amad27: In my answer there is a mention of the Stronger form of IVT and this is not specific to $0$. Using this theorem we obtain the $c, d$ of this answer.